# Why the removed row appears again in html table that removed by "jquery remove" when i use pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML table with a column including a deleting button in its rows. When I delete a row by ajax request, it works and it's getting deleted from the database. 
In my success function the row is removed from the table without refreshing page. Everything is ok so far.

But my table lenght is 50 rows. If I have more than 50 rows, some sort of pagination appears.

For example I removed a row from 1st page. This row disappears. Then I go to the second page and return again to the first page, my deleted row appears again. If I refresh the page, there is no problem. But if I use the pagination or something like this it appears. How can I solve this problem?

My remove function:

```
function deletetransfer() {
  var tra_id = $(this).data("tra_id");
  var data = 'tra_id=' + tra_id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "transfers/deletetransfer.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      $("table#transferlist tr#trid" + tra_id).remove();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: How does your pagination work? How does your html-markup look like?

Comment: My table is jquery datatable. I use its own pagination. And HTML structure is : 
<table>

<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
</tr>
<thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="PkFromDb"></td>
</tr>
<tbody>

Comment: Can you try to set up a working example we can play with?

Comment: Yes, i will set up an example. Please let me prepare.

Comment: Solved. I used empyt() instead of remove().